# Change background of ckeditor?

Tags: html, css, ckeditor, fckeditor

How do I change the background colour of CKEditor, where the user types the text? I need to do this dynamically but I cant find the element that needs to change. ANy idea of how to target it?

Comment: Use some browser developer tools to find out the name. In FireFox for example, you install FireBug, go to the page in question, click the arrow, click on the element on the page that interests you, and it will show you all the information you need to find out how to "target it".

Comment: Have you looked at the CKEditor docs?

Comment: Yes this does not tell you how to do it via javascript, it mentions skins. I did google it first before coming here.

Comment: @user1013512 Have you researched making a skin?

Comment: I dont want to make a skin, I just want to change the text background red

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.getBody().setStyle('background-color', 'red');
```

Where `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1` is an instance of editor - you can test this e.g. here: http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 0):

To change with 'myCss.css' file:

myJavascript:

```
CKEDITOR.document.$.body.className+=' nameofClass ';
```

myCss.css:

```
.nameofClass{
    background-color: 'blue';
}
```

config.js of ckEditor folder:

```
config.contentsCss = '/path/myCss.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change it with a change or click event:

```
<textarea id="content" class="main_editor" name="content"></textarea>
<input type="button" class="default-text" value="White" data-value="#ff0000" />

<script>
editor = CKEDITOR.replace("content");
$(document).on("click", ".default-text" , function(e) {
    var color = $(this).data('value');
    editor.document.$.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].style.color = color;
    editor.focus();
});
</script>
```

I use jquery mini colors and a change event to dynamically change the background (style.background = color).

Answer (score -1):

Use the Firebug plugin on FF or the developer tools of Chrome to find the correct element to style.

Comment: it's script based so nothing is revealed in chrome tools or firebug.