# How to change the background color of text editing area of CKEditor with respect to the color of text?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I have a CKEditor for editing the content of a blog. Sometimes there are blogs that got dark background color and therefore use white as font color. As the default background color of CKEditor text editing area is white, all text can only be seen with highlight.

[image]

While I want something like this (but only when the font color is white):

[image]

I am using CKEditor 4.6. How can I change the background color of the CKEditor on the fly according to the font color the user choose?

Comment: You mean the one that is already in the screenshot? It only change the color of the font, not the editor background color.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131426/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-container-in-ckeditor-with-color-palette

Comment: [I think I just answered that here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084687/change-background-of-ckeditor)

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to use the [Div Editing Area](http://ckeditor.com/addon/divarea) add-on, to inherit the web page CSS styles (font color and background color):

> This plugin uses a `<div>` element (instead of the traditional `<iframe>`
>   element) as the editable area in the themedui creator. Much similar to
>   inline editing, it benefits from allowing the editor content to
>   inherit from host page styles.